# How to create a redundant instance of Solr

Tags: solr, high-availability, disaster-recovery

I need to build out a fully redundant and resilient Solr search platform where search data is replicated between data centers.

Does Solr cluster provide any vehicle for this inter-datacenter replication to occur? If not in the engine, if I was to create a snapshot of the data and ship that across the wire and have a second Solr engine on the remote side sitting at idle waiting for the primary to die, would that work?

Looking for recommendations as I can not support a production implementation of Solr without having DR capability.

Answer (score 0):

SolrCloud is something that helps HA/DR (High Availability and Disaster Recovery). With ZooKeeper in picture, there is near-realtime support across clusters.

Here are a couple of resources:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud (updated 2017)
- https://support.lucidworks.com/entries/22180608-Solr-HA-DR-overview-3-x-and-4-0-SolrCloud- (Maily discusses Solr 3 and 4)

Previous SolrCloud reference:

- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud